# how to use different font for mathjax

Tags: javascript, php, css, fonts, mathjax

In my website I have the following css property

```
span, div {
    font-family: myfont !important;
}
```

It seems that Mathjax uses span and div tags for display math formulas. So this cause my website to load Mathjax more slowly.

I am looking for a way to use myfont in all the span and div elements in my website except for mathjax.

Thanks.

Comment: If you use `! important` you are going to override the CSS that MathJax applies, and there really isn't any way around that.  If yo are using `! important` because you are overriding some other CSS, perhaps you an change the other CSS to be more specific so the is only changes the font in certain situations, so you don't have to override with `! important` and can just use `font-family: myfont` instead.

Comment: @DavideCervone Thank you your comment solved my problem. I used font-family: myfont